# inline dplyr in R Markdown

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown

I'm looking to inline some R code into an essay I'm writing. The following is fine:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over \`r 2+2\` lazy dogs
```

> The quick brown fox jumped over 4 lazy dogs

But when I try to combine dplyr with the following dataframe:

```
structure(list(name = structure(c(2L, 1L, 3L), .Label = c("Cat", 
"Dog", "Horse"), class = "factor"), n = c(4L, 3L, 8L)), .Names = c("name", 
"n"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

it breaks:

```
The quick brown fox jumped over \`r as.numeric(temp %>% filter(name=="dog") %>% select(n)\` lazy dogs

Quitting from lines 80-81 (QuickBrown.Rmd)
Error in base::parse(text = code, keep.source = FALSE) : 
 <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: as.numeric(temp %>% filter(name=="Dog") %>% select(
   ^
```

Trying to use the chunk objects gets me closer, especially with results="asis":

````
The quick brown fox jumped over 
```{r results="asis", echo=FALSE}
df <- as.numeric(temp %>% filter(name=="Dog") %>% select(n))
print(df[,1][[1]])
```
lazy dogs
````

> The quick brown fox jumped over [1] 4 lazy dogs

but I can't work out how to get rid of the index number [1]. How can I best combine dplyr results inline with R Markdown or using the chunk, how can I get rid of the index number?

Comment: You might be able to use the `cat` function instead of `print`. Another option would be to use the chunk option to create a variable `n` and then call `n` inline like `The quick brown fox jumped over 'r n' lazy dogs`.

Comment: ah, `cat` works, thanks. I take it inline dplyer is not possible though: The quick brown fox jumped over \`r cat(as.numeric(temp %>% filter(name=="dog") %>% select(n))\` lazy dogs still breaks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would try

````
```{r, echo=FALSE}
library(magrittr) # for %$% extraction
x <- temp %>% filter(name=="Dog") %>% slice(1) %$% n)
```
````

The quick brown fox jumped over `r x` lazy dogs

---

But you can also use dplyr inline. I tested this successfully:

````
---
title: "test"
output: html_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(dplyr)
library(magrittr)
```

## R Markdown

here's a `r mtcars %>% slice(1) %$% gear` test with dplyr.
````

Comment: Thanks, that works. I've never met the %$% before, what does it do? My new code: The quick brown fox jumped over \`r temp %>% filter(name=="Dog") %$% n\` lazy dogs

Comment: @pluke, `%$%` is used to extract an atomic vector from a data.frame in a pipe (and that (a vector) is what you want to use in your inline code)