# Extract value from tibble in R markdown inline code

Tags: r, dplyr, r-markdown, knitr, tibble

I'm looking to access a value from a tibble using inline code in an R Markdown document.

The following code gives me a 1 x 2 tibble.

```
#library(tidyverse)
#library(knitr)

# Minimal working example
df <- tibble(
  Event = c("Swimming","Swimming","Swimming","Camping","Hiking","Hiking")
)
df

# Creates 1 row x 2 column
df %>% count(Event) %>% slice(which.max(n))
```

If I create an object in a code chunk, I can select [1,1] and report that inline:

```
temp <- df %>% count(Event) %>% slice(which.max(n))

# The most popular event was `r temp[1,1]`.

# which becomes "The most popular event was Swimming."
```

Is there a way to do that within my dplyr pipes without creating a new object? Ideally, I would be able to do it all via inline code, something like:

```
`r df %>% count(Event) %>% slice(which.max(n)) %>% df[1,1]`  # fails
```

Stepping back, I'm looking for a generalizable technique to use to select particular rows and cells from within a series of dplyr commands *without* creating new objects along the way.

Comment: I think this question can help you out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37345268/inline-dplyr-in-r-markdown

Comment: Yes, very helpful. Let's see if I can make it apply to this case...

Comment: you might try `r df %>% count(Event) %>% slice(which.max(n)) %>% {.[1,1]}` . Well, if you include this in a sentence, you might want to add `%>% tolower`

Answer (score 2):

Your line of code that you want to display inline doesn't run even when not in R Markdown, try it in the console. When using special operators like `[`, `[[`, `$` with the pipe, you need to specify them in the prefix rather than infix form like other functions, like this. Note the comparison of your attempted code, and alternatively using `[[` to drill down and select just the text instead of returning a tibble.

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  Event = c("Swimming","Swimming","Swimming","Camping","Hiking","Hiking")
)

df %>% count(Event) %>% slice(which.max(n)) %>% `[`(1,1)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 1
#>   Event   
#>   <chr>   
#> 1 Swimming
df %>% count(Event) %>% slice(which.max(n)) %>% `[[`("Event")
#> [1] "Swimming"
```

However, this doesn't quite solve your problem because R Markdown uses backticks to denote the inline code, and it's complicated to change the parsing rules that `knitr` uses to find and evaluate inline code, so here it would think the code ended at `` `[` ``. So you can instead use the `magrittr` aliases for these functions, `extract` and `extract2` in inline code:

```r
Most popular event was `r df %>% count(Event) %>% slice(which.max(n)) %>% magrittr::extract2("Event")`
```

which correctly prints `Most popular event was Swimming` in the rendered markdown.

Comment: This is really helpful. Do you know of a more generalizable solution that would allow me to select, say, [2,1] or [2,2] from a tibble using inline code? Your elegant solution works well when the result I want is in [1,1]. I'm trying to think about other use cases...

Comment: Just change the indices in `extract2`! If you want a different column, use that number/name. Here because you did `which.max` it's a one row table, so selecting a column is also selecting a single element. If there were more rows, add another `[` to the end of the pipe to get the element you want.

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning several ways to do this - thanks all!

**1.** Following @labatnok:

```
r df %>% count(Event) %>% slice(which.max(n)) %>% {.[1,1]}
```

**2.** Following @mmyoung77:

```
`r df %>% count(Event) %>% arrange(desc(n)) %>% slice(1) %$% Event`

# result
[1] "Swimming"
```

This approach avoids using "which.max." The "1" in `slice(1)` indicates the row, then `%$% Event` indicates the column (by name).

It's not quite as easy to follow what is happening as base R's `[1,1]`, but it gets the job done.

**3.** Following @Mo Alfaifi:

```
(df %>% count(Event) %>% arrange(desc(n)))[1,1]
```

This approach makes it easier  to tell which row/column you are selecting. It also avoids needing to name the column.

**4.** Following @Colum You:

```
df %>% count(Event) %>% slice(which.max(n)) %>% magrittr::extract2("Event")
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
df %>% count(Event)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Event        n
# 1 Camping      1
# 2 Hiking       2
# 3 Swimming     3

# To get the first row
(df %>% count(Event))[1,]

# Event       n
# 1 Camping   1
```

Comment: Close to this. This was a good idea  - I elaborated on your answer in mine.